# react input field show the input althogh the user input is not legal, the value suppose to be numeric and the state doesnt change until it is numeric

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my input field is showing letters it recieved as inputs althogh its state is not updated due to the test i have at the onchange event.
for example: input field="dldld" and the state will be "".

my onchange function:

```
const handleChangeAdRentContent = (e) => {
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    if (e.target.min) {
      if (e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value)) {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        setInputAdConentRent({ ...inputAdConentRent, [name]: value });
      
        return;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  };
```

this is the input field:

```
 <label
              key={masters[index].name + masters[index].adID}
              className={notdisplayRent}
            >
              <span>{masters[index].free_text}</span>
              <input
                type="text"
                name={masters[index].name}
                min={masters[index].min_value}
                max={masters[index].max_value}
                id={masters[index].name}
                required={masters[index].required}
                value={inputAdConentRent.name}
                onChange={handleChangeAdRentContent}
              />
            </label>
```

this is the input it consitst of an object of many inputs controlled by [key,value]

```
const [inputAdConentRent, setInputAdConentRent] = useState({});
```

thank you very much